# How can I change my folders name without loosing public access

Tags: file

I am remoddeling my web site and I am trying to make it responsive. With this, I would like to clean and tidy up a bit...

I used to put all my images and files in the root folder. Now I would like to put them all (over 3000 elements) in a folder called `Archiv`. The resulting problem would be, that I had to rename all the links and i.e. banners which I published would not be accessible anymore...
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: no not without changing the links inside your html etc

Comment: Add more details to your question, for example, do you use a specific CMS? or links are saved into database or plain HTML file? This question is unclear.

Comment: No CMS, plain html.

Comment: no database, even no .php, The only issue are the broken links...

Answer (score 0):

Consider following option. Define a new virtual host on another port, say 88 or 8000. Make your old site available via this port. Move your old site to any directory you wish and point virtual host to that directory. Then your root directory for the new version of your web site is free and you can do your new web site from scratch.

Comment: Do you mean with virtual host setting up a wamp server?

Comment: Why wamp? You said you have a web site. What web server is it running on - Apache, Nginx, MS IIS, other? In this web server define a new virtual host with different portf and point it to the current content directory. The default virtual host can be pointed then to a new directory without the old stuff.

Comment: And why you say "setting up"? You said you already have a web site.

Comment: I do have a website hosted by a company but not on my own server. I asked them, and they responded they could not change the ports.

Comment: What about some htaccess redirection? I have no idea how, but could this be an alternative?